# How to add Internet Connection Problem Dialog in android app on Async Task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to add Internet Connection Problem Dialog in my Async Task subclass. I tried many methods but the same error happened when my internet not connected.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.yasht.cricketapp, PID: 12793
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.io.InputStream
    at com.example.yasht.cricketapp.m_Rss.Downloader.onPostExecute(Downloader.java:66)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Error Pointing On 66 line:

[image: click here to see]

Please comment If you want any other information.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting `data` into inputStream, if you want to create this object you should do something like : `ByteArrayInputStream( data.getBytes() )`

probably you should post your onExecute too to see what are you trying to do